# Show the following defines a topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> For the open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ take those sets that are open in the
> usual sense and periodic with period $1$ ( $t \in U \iff t+1 \in U \;
> , \forall U \; \; open $) PROVE this is a topology on R

#### attempt:

I am having some trouble proving this.Trivially $\varnothing $ satisfies this and $\mathbb{R}$ as well.

Now, if we consider a colletion $(U_{\alpha})$ of open sets, then take $x \in \bigcup U_{\alpha}$

then  $x+1 \in \bigcup U_{\alpha}$   it follows that  $x+1\in U_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$  so the union is in the collection

finally, take $U_1$ and $U_2$ and let $x \in U_1$ and $x \in U_2$ so$x+1 \in U_1$ and $x+1 \in U_2$ and so $x + 1 \in U_1 \cap U_2$

so $U_1 \cap U_2$ is in the collection

is this enough to prove this collection is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the open sets have the extra condition

$$\forall x \in U: x+1 \in U\tag{1}$$

which is voidly satisfied for $\emptyset$ and trivial for $U=X$.

If $U_i, i \in I$ is a collection of periodic Euclidean open sets, $U:=\bigcup_i U_i$ is Euclidean open (we know that the Euclidean topology is a topology) and to check it is still periodic, take any $x \in U$. Then $x \in U_i$ for *some* $i$, and as $U_i$ is periodic, $x+1 \in U_i$ and so $x+1 \in U$. So $U$ is periodic (it satisfies $(1)$).

The finite intersection you did OK.

Comment: Didnt I do exactly what you did ?

Comment: @Theoneandonly you have wrong stuff like “if $x+1$ is in $U$” which is irrelevant. You start with $x$ in the union etc. So the exact formulation matters!

Comment: thanks sir, I just wonder why is this topology useful if anything

Comment: @Theoneandonly maybe for a following exercise. Or they’re gonna show we get a space homeomorphic to the circle?